# Max speed and acceleration in Gpointing-device-settings have no effect

Tags: mouse, thinkpad, synaptics, trackpad

Trying to get my Synaptics trackpad (on a Thinkpad T420) dialed in. Almost perfect, but the max speed and acceleration settings in Gpointing Device Settings appear to have absolutely no effect, so I'm totally reliant on minimum speed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to see the same issue in Ubuntu Mate.   To adjust the speed the old-school way, you can use the xinput command line tool.   For example on a Dell XPS 13:

```
# list your devices
xinput 

# list properties
xinput --list-props "CyPS/2 Cypress Trackpad" 

# increase acceleration 
xinput --set-prop "CyPS/2 Cypress Trackpad" 265 2
```

The --set-prop commands can be turning into a script and added to your Startup Applications.

I haven't found a GUI that sets all the touchpad options, yet.